# Type alias "Bar" is not a member of type "Foo"

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I have the following setup:

```swift
// MARK: Basis

public class Foo {
    public typealias Bar = [String : Int]
}


func take(fooBar: Foo.Bar) {
    print(fooBar)
}


// MARK: Problems

public typealias FooBar = Foo.Bar



public extension Dictionary
    where Key == FooBar.Key,
        Value == FooBar.Value {

    func baz() {
        take(fooBar: self as! FooBar)
    }
}


// MARK: Usages

FooBar().baz()
take(fooBar: [:])
```

This seems fine to me, but I get this error:

```
main.swift:16:31: error: type alias 'Bar' is not a member type of 'Foo'
public typealias FooBar = Foo.Bar
                          ~~~ ^
```

I'm terribly confused... it's right there; I should be able to see it.

Here's the most confusing part: If I comment-out the `extension Dictionary` block and the call-site of `baz()`, then everything works fine.

That is to say, **this compiles and runs no-problem:**

```
public class Foo {
    public typealias Bar = [String : Int]
}


func take(fooBar: Foo.Bar) {
    print(fooBar)
}


public typealias FooBar = Foo.Bar


take(fooBar: [:])
```

So my question: **What's going on, and how do I work around it?**

Comment: Note: If I declare `FooBar = [String : Int]` and `Bar = FooBar`, it claims "Type alias 'FooBar' references itself"

Comment: If you insert `let fb = FooBar()` between the typealias and the extension then it compiles again – which makes me suspect a compiler bug.

Comment: Filed [SR-6179](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6179)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Swift compiler. You can track it here: [SR-6179](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6179)